# Apollo Authentication with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, gatsby

I am trying to implement the *Authentication* workflow officially described in the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html) as I did before in other projects, but this time using **Gatsby**.

The idea seems pretty straightforward. Need to create/update `gatsby-browser.js` like when using [redux](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-redux/gatsby-browser.js) but to initialise the `ApolloClient` and pass through `ApolloProvider`.

Something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: process.env.ENDPOINT_URI,
  credentials: 'same-origin',     
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache().restore({}),
})

exports.replaceRouterComponent = ({ history }) => {
  const ConnectedRouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router history={history}>{children}</Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )

  return ConnectedRouterWrapper
}
```

Then login using

```
<Mutation
  mutation={LOGIN_MUTATION}
  refetchQueries={[{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }]}
>
  {/*...*/}
</Mutation>
```

and in another *Component* with something like the *Status* (where, if logged in shows x otherwise y):

```
<Query query={CURRENT_USER_QUERY} fetchPolicy="network-only">
{/*...*/}
</Query>
```

**The problem**

With this configuration, when the login receives `data` (so, credentials are ok), I save the token received in `localStorage` but the *Status* component do the `Query` with the previous (empty) `token`, so shows logged out, also doing something like `history.push('/')` after login.

Refreshing the page, since the item in `localStorage` was saved before, the *Status* shows as logged in.

**Expected behaviour**

The idea is to have the *Status* component updated after login avoiding doing a refresh of the page, for this reason I added `refetchQueries={[{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }]}`.

I tried some things like pass `props` (no needed in case I change the `route` and use `withRouter` in the *Status* component), but seems to late, the `Query` was fired without the new `token`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is probably your *Status* component needs to be re-render only after the the token saved into `localStorage`. Right now it's probably re-render too early.

You can try wrapping your *Status* component with another wrapper component, and check for the token existence before rendering the *Status* component.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the response, I tried what you said but the problem persists. So, after login, console.logging the localStorage item in the _Status_ Component seems to be set, so I conditionally rendering the <Query> Component, but seems that the request sent to server doesn't have the token.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is related to how the links are defined. IMO, the AuthLink should be defined before the HttpLink (as middleware):

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    authLink,
    httpLink
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache().restore({}),
})
```

While the documentation says that concat and from do the same thing, order is important. You want to have the context set before sending the request.

Comment: seems that the issue is related to _Apollo_. Here are three open issues that expand the situation: [2009](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2009), [630](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/630) and [461](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/461).